# How to replace NULL with integer value in DB2?

Tags: sql, replace, null, db2

I am trying to replace NULL with integer value 1 (or 0 if done in the nested sql-statment) in the column "Antal tillgängliga språk". Some of the rows get the right value, but som get NULL. I guess that is because my nested sql-statement only returns what matches my where-clause. There is some bokid witch don't have any Språk from the xpath-expression.

- I have tried using SELECT COALESCE(COUNT(Språk)+1, 1) AS "Antal
  tillgängliga språk", but that did not work.
- I have also tried SELECT IFNULL(COUNT(Språk)+1, 1) AS "Antal
  tillgängliga språk", but that did not work either.
- I have also tried changing the where-clause in the nested
  sql-statment to use FULL JOIN witch also didn't work.

Now I am out of ideas, can someone help me?

```
SELECT DISTINCT Title AS "Titel", 
    OriginalLanguage AS "Orginalspråk", 
    Genre AS "Genre", 
    (SELECT COUNT(Id)
    FROM Edition
    WHERE Edition.Book = Book.Id) AS "Antal upplagor",
    (SELECT COUNT(Språk)+1 AS "Antal tillgängliga språk"
    FROM (SELECT Book.Id AS bokid, Språk
        FROM Edition, XMLTABLE('$TRANSLATIONS//Translation/@Language' 
            COLUMNS Språk VARCHAR(20) PATH '.'), Book
        WHERE Edition.Book = Book.Id
        GROUP BY Språk, Book.Id)
    WHERE bokid = Book.Id
    GROUP BY bokid),
    (SELECT COUNT(Author)
    FROM Authorship
    WHERE Authorship.Book = Book.Id) AS "Antal författare",
    (SELECT MIN(Year)
    FROM Edition
    WHERE Edition.Book = Book.Id) AS "År första upplaga"
FROM Book
```

The +1 is to count all available languages of the books, all translations + original language.

Comment: Need wrap IFNULL with COUNT instead of the other way around perhaps?

Comment: Wrap the entire subquery in your coalesce. and alias the field as you did the others

Comment: Use Derived tables instead of inline selects for performance reasons.  Better to run once the query get the values and join than run once for each record.  Put another way; many (perhaps not all) engines will run each subquery once for each row since you have 5 subqueries 5* number of rows; vs 5 times.  Additionally a cross join between book and edition when an inner join makes more sense  As it stands this is very unreadable IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your COALESCE outside of your sub-selects

```
SELECT DISTINCT Title AS "Titel", 
    OriginalLanguage AS "Orginalspråk", 
    Genre AS "Genre", 
    COALESCE((SELECT COUNT(Id)
    FROM Edition
    WHERE Edition.Book = Book.Id),1) AS "Antal upplagor",
    COALESCE((SELECT COUNT(Språk)+1 AS "Antal tillgängliga språk"
    FROM (SELECT Book.Id AS bokid, Språk
        FROM Edition, XMLTABLE('$TRANSLATIONS//Translation/@Language' 
            COLUMNS Språk VARCHAR(20) PATH '.'), Book
        WHERE Edition.Book = Book.Id
        GROUP BY Språk, Book.Id)
    WHERE bokid = Book.Id
    GROUP BY bokid),1),
    COALESCE((SELECT COUNT(Author)
    FROM Authorship
    WHERE Authorship.Book = Book.Id),1) AS "Antal författare",
    COALESCE((SELECT MIN(Year)
    FROM Edition
    WHERE Edition.Book = Book.Id),1) AS "År första upplaga"
FROM Book
```

Comment: This looks right to me; other than I'd have pulled "Antal tillgängliga språk" to alias the column nicer.

Comment: Yes, you had the alias in the wrong place in your original SQL

Answer (score 0):

The query could also be written like this. It is somewhat a matter of style which way you prefer to do things, but generally correlated sub-selects are not easy to debug, and generally not as clear as joining separate selects together.

```
SELECT B.Title                    AS "Titel"
,      B.OriginalLanguage         AS "Orginalspråk"
,      B.Genre                    AS "Genre"
,      COALESCE(E.Editions + 1,1) AS "Antal upplagor"
,      COALESCE(S.Språk    + 1,1) AS "Antal tillgängliga språk"
,      COALESCE(A.Authors  + 1,1) AS "Antal författare"
,      COALESCE(E.Min_Year + 1,1) AS "År första upplaga"
FROM Book B
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(   SELECT  Book
    ,       COUNT(*)        AS Editions
    ,       MIN(Year)       AS Min_Year
    FROM Edition
    GROUP BY
            Book
) E
ON
    E.Book = B
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(   SELECT Book
    ,      COUNT(Author)   AS Authors
    FROM Authorship
    GROUP BY
            Book
) A
ON
    A.Book = B.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN      
(   SELECT  Book
    ,       COUNT(DISTINCT Språk)   AS Språk
    FROM Edition
    ,    XMLTABLE('$TRANSLATIONS//Translation/@Language'  COLUMNS Språk VARCHAR(20) PATH '.')
    GROUP BY
            Book
) S
ON
    S.Book = B.Id
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd refactor the query to something like (UNTESTED)

I'd rather get the data one time for all records in memory instead of running the query for each and every row.  Performance variance will not matter that much until the table sizes grow; though Språk generation may cause that notice in performance degredration to be realized sooner rather than later.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Title AS "Titel", 
    OriginalLanguage AS "Orginalspråk", 
    Genre AS "Genre", 
    "Antal upplagor",
    coalesce("Antal tillgängliga språk",0) AS "Antal tillgängliga språk",
    coalesce("Antal författare", 0) AS "Antal författare",
    coalesce("År första upplaga",0) AS "År första upplaga"
FROM Book
LEFT JOIN (SELECT COUNT(Språk)+1 AS "Antal tillgängliga språk", bokid
           FROM (SELECT Book.Id AS bokid, Språk
                 FROM Edition
                    , XMLTABLE('$TRANSLATIONS//Translation/@Language' COLUMNS Språk VARCHAR(20) PATH '.')
                 INNER JOIN Book
                    ON Edition.Book = Book.Id
                 GROUP BY Språk, Book.Id)
           GROUP BY bokid)  BE
  ON BE.bokid = Book.Id
LEFT JOIN  (SELECT Book, COUNT(Author) AS "Antal författare"
            FROM Authorship
            GROUP BY Book)  A
  ON A.Book = Book.Id
LEFT JOIN  (SELECT Book, MIN(Year) AS "År första upplaga", Count(ID) AS "Antal upplagor"
            FROM Edition
            GROUP BY Book) E
  ON E.Book = Book.Id
```

Comment: Performance wise, Db2 will de-correlate where it can in the optimized SQL/access plan,  but yes, in general the above will avoid the possibility of poor performance due to correlated subselects being executed for each row

Comment: I know each engine and version of engine has different optimization plans; but in general I've found the derived tables to be "safer" bet even if the engine can optimize the access plan.  Keeping track of each engine's specific method and for each version has been enough of a headache that I just play it safe anymore.  I agree; it is a matter of style on most current engines / versions but I also find maintenance easier.  I mean a FROM is intended to identify all the source data in the select.how did you get a count from authorship if it wasn't in the from?  It just seems like bad form.